# TTimer.OnTimer does not fire

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I made 2 forms in one project, form2 incorporated into the parent form I use form2 more details such as the use of frames, I use this code in the parent application formcreate ..

for example:

```
form2 := tform2.Create(self);
form2.Parent := panel1;
form2.Visible := true;
```

form 2 made ​​it into form1(parent application)

the problem is when i enter this code in the timer component when in the run (F9) nothing has changed at all

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  form2.Label1.Caption:= ipclient.LocalIP;
end;
```

component used in the parent application is: = 
Timer1

components are used in form2: = 
label1 to record the local ip

so basically how to make form2 provide full access to all of the parent application in order to be set in the parent application can run all?

Comment: Did you set `Timer1.Enabled` property to `True`?

Comment: I understood it perfectly, unfair to mark it down.

Comment: Is it possible that the Form2 referenced in the creation code is not the same Form2 referenced in the timer event?  Is it possible that LocalIP is returning a blank string?  What if you replace it with a string constant?  Is it possible the event isn't being fired?  Try adding a MessageBeep to the event.  Do you hear it?

Comment: @J__ Please could you edit the question to make it clear then

Comment: @DavidDubois I downloaded the project source from the Dropbox comment below and it worked first time (in Delphi XE3) so it appears that the logic is correct. morphictux, perhaps something is preventing access to your IP Address? As David suggests, what happens if you just set the Form2.Label1.Caption to a fixed value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just set up a demo project to do exactly what you have done and it has worked first time. Is the Timer1.Enabled property set to True, and is the Interval value low enough to actually be firing?

Also, where is the code behind the ipClient.LocalIP method?

I wrote my own method for getting the IP Address using Winsock, and when I ran the program, the Form2.Label1.Caption changed to my IP address after 2 seconds (Timer1.Interval = 2000).

Comment: This also worked for me. It works slightly better if you remove the Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2) from the project source file, Project1.dpr.
Does setting the Active property to True on the TidIPWatch component help? (I didn't need to).